# Database Cleaner unable to detect ORM in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, database-cleaner, ruby-on-rails-5

The error below is displayed when `$ rspec` is executed:

> No known ORM was detected!  Is ActiveRecord, DataMapper, Sequel, MongoMapper, Mongoid, Moped, or CouchPotato, Redis or Ohm loaded? (DatabaseCleaner::NoORMDetected)

This is a snippet from the **spec_helper.rb** file:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end
```

The *Rails* application in question uses *ActiveRecord* as the ORM and the [documentation for Database Cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) states that it checks for *ActiveRecord* first.

The *Rails* version for the application is `5.0.0.beta2`.

What is the cause of the error and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The cause:**

The error is caused by the absence of a model. Because there is no model, no *ORM* has been specified by the application. As a result, *DatabaseCleaner* cannot choose an appropriate strategy.

**Solution**

At least one model should be created. This can be done via the `rails generate scaffold` or `rails generate model` commands.